# JOOQ date as is, ignore timezone

Tags: mysql, jdbc, jooq

I get `2019-09-01` from a date column in SQL but 1 day before while use Jooq.  I think it is because my application ( OS level and Java frontend ) uses `US/Eastern`, but the DB uses UTC.  See the SQL below:

```
select kpisd1, convert_tz( kpisd1, 'US/Eastern', @@session.time_zone), convert_tz( kpisd1, @@session.time_zone, 'US/Eastern' ), @@session.time_zone from kpi where kpiprc = '00006330263815' and kpikpi = 'TURN' and kpists = 'HIST';
+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| kpisd1              | convert_tz( kpisd1, 'US/Eastern', @@session.time_zone) | convert_tz( kpisd1, @@session.time_zone, 'US/Eastern' ) | @@session.time_zone |
+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| 2019-09-01 00:00:00 | 2019-09-01 04:00:00                                    | 2019-08-31 20:00:00                                     | UTC                 |
+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

My C program actually, which is what is updating the database, does not really do any timezone conversion before adding it to the DB. It gets the date based on the OS timezone, and then uses that date.  So if it adds 9/1/2019, I expect to get back 9/1/2019.  I tried `select date( kpisd1 )`, but that also did not work.  Even when I print out the raw java.sql.Date, it does not match the DB, which means it is probably being converted inside JDBC, I guess.  Any ideas?

My only other option is to convert the DB time zone from UTC to "US/Eastern" ( to match the timezone on my application server ), but I need to research the ramifications of that, so am trying to not rush to such a drastic step ( this is a production environment ).

Comment: Are you using `datetime` in MySQL for storing a date that doesn’t need time of day? Why? You may also want to [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we see exactly what you are trying.

Comment: jOOQ doesn't do any extra time zone conversion magic on top of JDBC, so this is more how your JDBC driver works. There are numerous ways to fix this, ideally not on a per-query basis, but by setting all time zones to UTC...

Comment: @OleV.V. `datetime` usage instead of just plain `date` is a holdover from other database systems we used, I expect.  To be honest, it never mattered because our C code does not care, just takes it as is.  Regardless, the key is an application running in one time zone ( NOT UTC ) against a database in UTC.

Comment: @LukasEder I cannot use UTC everywhere, not at this point.  Maybe we should have done that from the beginning, but it was always easier to just use our local timezone, so that is what we have done.  I just missed the impact when we setup this database, did not realize the ramifications of not changing the timezone from UTC to our local timezone at the DB level.  So, I really need to do this on a per-query basis, unless those methods or really really bad ideas.  Can you point me in the right direction so I can evaluate some of those ideas and see if any fit my use case?

Comment: MySQL's JDBC driver has a *lot* of JDBC URL properties which controls the behavior when it comes to time zones. I recommend you take a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html and test some of the properties like `useTimezone` or `noTimezoneConversionForDateType`.

Comment: Please have a look at my workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59933788/3377941

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on advice from @knutwannheden, I changed:

```
                databaseUrl = "jdbc:mysql://" + host.trim() + ":3306/" + db.trim();
```

to

```
                Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                databaseUrl = "jdbc:mysql://" + host.trim() + ":3306/" + db.trim() +
                        "?serverTimezone=" + now.getTimeZone().getID();
```

I chose `serverTimezone` based on the documentation referenced above:

> serverTimezone
>
> Override detection/mapping of time zone. Used when time zone from
>   server doesn't map to Java time zone
>
> Since version: 3.0.2

Yes, in my case this is actually not true - my MySql server is set to UTC, which does map to the client, BUT since I did not want it mapping, I tried this and it worked.  I did NOT try the other timezone parameters because this one worked right away, but there is a decent chance that `noTimezoneConversionForDateType` or one of the other time zone parameters would have worked.

If anyone has an concerns about this solution, please mention them.  I am sort of cheating, I expect, but I cannot think of any really dangerous side effects right now.